# JavaFx: NPE at Bindings.when().then().otherwise()

Tags: java, javafx, binding, nullpointerexception, javafx-8

I have a problem using `Bindings.when.then.otherwise`.

Here is a simple example:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private SubController subPaneController;

    @FXML
    private Label sum;

    // Simple flag, ofc I can use any condition as "when" instead of this.
    private BooleanProperty subPaneLoaded = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // ofc NPE since subPane is not yet initialized
        //sum.textProperty().bind(subPaneController.sumBinding().asString()); 

        // but here the "then" is evaluated even if "when" is false 
        sum.textProperty().bind(Bindings.when(subPaneLoaded)
                .then(subPaneController.sumBinding().asString()) // and NPE here at evaluation.
                .otherwise(""));
    }

}

public class SubController {

    /**
     * Calculates the sum of a few properties used in this controller.
     */
    IntegerBinding sumBinding() {
        return Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> 0);
    }

}
```

The problem is as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46123467/nullpointerexception-in-binding) is answered, the *then* or *otherwise* is evaluated independently of the result of *when*.

I cannot really use the `Bindings.select()` or at least I didn't manage to get it working.

My sub controller is initialized when that module is opened by pressing a button. Every change made in that module I want to be displayed in the main view as a text of a label and of course to be updated *live*, that's why I want to use the implementation I just showed.

If you have any other suggestion how can be solved to achieve a live update without NPE I will appreciate it.

[Easy binding](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) is not a solution for me, since I cannot use this 3rd party framework.

I am using java 1.8.0_172

Comment: Could you show us your stack trace / error message?

Comment: you know how to ask a good question (with [mcve]) - please do it!

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways:

#### 1. Listener

`When` is just an API convenience of a binding, which is a convenience of listeners. If the behavior doesn't suit you<sup>1</sup>, create your own:

```
subPaneLoaded.addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
    @Override
    public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
        sum.textProperty().bind(subPaneController.sumBinding().asString());
        subPaneLoaded.removeListener(this);
    }
});
```

When the `SubController` is ready (given you control `subPaneLoaded` well), you register the binding for the label, which is now guaranteed to be non-null. You then also remove the binding from `subPaneLoaded` because it has done its job.

#### 2. @FXML initialize()

You can set the binding up in the `initialize()` method of the controller:

```
public class SubController { 

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        sum.textProperty().bind(sumBinding().asString()); 
    }

    IntegerBinding sumBinding() {
        return Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> 0);
    }
}
```

This method is called when the FXML content is loaded (see [Introduction to FXML](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers)), which should also avoid the NPE. You will just need a way to make `sum` accessible to it.

I think the 2nd approach is cleaner. A one-time listener is a bit odd, but still fine.

---

<sup>1</sup> The eager evaluation behavior doesn't suit most users, so it is scheduled to be changed in the future.

Comment: These solutions are more or less workaroudnds, I don't really want to use the second solution even if it is cleaner, because my `SubController` shouldn't know about the sum label, since it is not the only Controller who adds information to that label. The first approach could be fine, but as you mentioned its a little bit weird to use a single time listener.

Comment: @Sunflame Any solution will be a workaround since we can't change the behavior of `When` right now, and you also asked for "*any other suggestion*", which basically means workarounds. Without a [MCVE] this is all I can propose.